# Lemmatize French text

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

I have some text in French that I need to process in some ways. For that, I need to:

- First, tokenize the text into words
- Then lemmatize those words to avoid processing the same root more than once

As far as I can see, the wordnet lemmatizer in the NLTK only works with English. I want something that can return "vouloir" when I give it "voudrais" and so on. I also cannot tokenize properly because of the apostrophes. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[**Here**](http://osdir.com/ml/python.nltk.devel/2007-06/msg00018.html)'s an old but relevant comment by an nltk dev. Looks like most advanced stemmers in nltk are all English specific:

> The nltk.stem module currently contains 3 stemmers: the Porter 
>   stemmer, the Lancaster stemmer, and a Regular-Expression based 
>   stemmer. The Porter stemmer and Lancaster stemmer are both English- 
>   specific. The regular-expression based stemmer can be customized to 
>   use any regular expression you wish. So you should be able to write  a
>   simple stemmer for non-English languages using the regexp stemmer. 
>   For example, for french:
>
> ```
> from nltk import stem
> stemmer = stem.Regexp('s$|es$|era$|erez$|ions$| <etc> ')
> ```
>
> But you'd need to come up with the language-specific regular 
>   expression yourself. For a more advanced stemmer, it would probably 
>   be necessary to add a new module. (This might be a good student 
>   project.)
>
> For more information on the regexp stemmer:
>
> http://nltk.org/doc/api/nltk.stem.regexp.Regexp-class.html
>
> -Edward

Note: the link he gives is dead, see [**here**](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#module-nltk.stem.regexp) for the current regexstemmer documentation.

The more recently added [**snowball stemmer**](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#module-nltk.stem.snowball) appears to be able to stem French though. Let's put it to the test:

```
>>> from nltk.stem.snowball import FrenchStemmer
>>> stemmer = FrenchStemmer()
>>> stemmer.stem('voudrais')
u'voudr'
>>> stemmer.stem('animaux')
u'animal'
>>> stemmer.stem('yeux')
u'yeux'
>>> stemmer.stem('dors')
u'dor'
>>> stemmer.stem('couvre')
u'couvr'
```

As you can see, some results are a bit dubious.

Not quite what you were hoping for, but I guess it's a start.

Comment: yea it's disappointing there's no stemmer for non-english languages. what I ended up doing actually is that I tokenized the words on punctuation, then I removed all residual one-letter articles (such as the remaining l in "l'ensemble" for example). I then used a listing of words and corresponding lemmata, specifically the one hosted at http://www.limsi.fr/Individu/anne/OLDlexique.txt, which was referenced by several posts online, it did the trick.
The snowball stemmer looks like it's working too, thanks Junuxx. :)

Comment: My French is not too good, but I'm unclear what you're expecting here.  It is stemming the words, afaict; it is not lemmatizing them, which is a different task.  That is, it's returning the stem, not the form that you would find in a dictionary (hence the lack of infinitival suffixes on verbs).  That is by design; that is what a stemmer does.

Comment: Yes that's a good distinction to make. Nevertheless I'd say animaux -> anima, voudrais -> vou might make more sense than the above output. Completely irregular plurals like yeux are tricky; I guess one has to grudgingly accept it as a stem.

Answer (score 27):

The best solution I found is spacy, it seems to do the job

To install:

```
pip3 install spacy
python3 -m spacy download fr_core_news_md
```

To use:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')

doc = nlp(u"voudrais non animaux yeux dors couvre.")
for token in doc:
    print(token, token.lemma_)
```

Result:

```
voudrais vouloir
non non
animaux animal
yeux oeil
dors dor
couvre couvrir
```

checkout the documentation for more details: https://spacy.io/models/fr && https://spacy.io/usage

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with TreeTagger ? I haven't try but this app can work in french

http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/
http://txm.sourceforge.net/installtreetagger_fr.html

Comment: gosh, treetaggers give unsupervised lemmas, i would advise to stay away from it if possible.

Comment: Can I please know how do you use treetagger for stemming the words? from what I understood with treetagger we can just pos tag words.

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing Machine Learning algorithms on your text, you may use n-grams instead of word tokens. It is not strictly lemmatization but it detects series of n similar letters and it is supprisingly powerful to gather words with the same meaning.

I use sklearn's function `CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb')` and for some specific text, it is way more efficient than bag of words.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a text mining project in a French bank, I recommend the package **cltk**.

`install cltk`
`from cltk.lemmatize.french.lemma import LemmaReplacer`

more details in [cltk](http://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/french.html)

Comment: The cltk appears to be for French up until the 14th century, no?  Am I misreading its documentation?  Surely the spelling of French has changed (some) since then, no?  And there are new words?  Like the infamous 'weekend'...

Comment: Exactly, it is written french, but it's for Old French. (Contributor of CLTK here).