# Good way to add terms to python pattern singularize

Tags: python, nlp

I am using python pattern to get the singular form of English nouns.

```
    In [1]: from pattern.en import singularize
    In [2]: singularize('patterns')
    Out[2]: 'pattern'
    In [3]: singularize('gases')
    Out[3]: 'gase'
```

I am solving the problem in the second example by defining

```
    def my_singularize(strn):
        '''
        Return the singular of a noun. Add special cases to correct pattern generic rules.
        '''
        exceptionDict = {'gases':'gas','spectra':'spectrum','cross':'cross','nuclei':'nucleus'}
        try:
            return exceptionDict[strn]
        except:
            return singularize(strn)
```

Is there a better way to do this, e.g. add to the rules of pattern, or make the `exceptionDict` somehow internal to pattern?

Comment: How can you expect to catch all the exceptions in the English language (words like nuclei)? Are you using a finite number of words as your input, and you know all of them? You won't get anywhere trying to define all of the word exceptions, I can guarantee you.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't thinking of catching all exceptions. However, my corpus is limited to scientific literature, which might make it easier. I guess the question is: does pattern already have a list of exceptions somewhere, so that I can add to that, instead of my own function?

Comment: why not use something like a lemmatizer??

Comment: @ shyamupa: Thanks, I did not know what to look for, I guess. After a quick test the [nltk lemmatizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771918/how-do-i-do-word-stemming-or-lemmatization) seems to work for most of my cases. I still need to check how much it slows things down, but I might be willing to live with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you would be better off by lemmatizing the words.
Its part of [nltk stemming module](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#module-nltk.stem.wordnet).

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
test_words = ['gases', 'spectrum','cross','nuclei']
%timeit [wnl.lemmatize(wrd) for wrd in test_words]

10000 loops, best of 3: 60.5 µs per loop
```

compared to your function

```
%timeit [my_singularize(wrd) for wrd in test_words]
1000 loops, best of 3: 162 µs per loop
```

nltk lemmatizing performs better.

Comment: Could you add the import clause to use this wnl module ?

Comment: @Josir Added :)

Comment: How do we use it for french word?

Comment: @mee i havent directly worked on french language but there is one discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131139/lemmatize-french-text

Comment: @heaven00 Thank you for your answer, I will try the spacy solution. I think it is the best.