# Regex to get rid of the last term with conditions

Tags: python, regex

I would like to write a regex to remove the last character from a string, if the character is a (s).

However in doing so I would like to retain the (s) if it is preceded by another (s).

Example.

The output of `Apples` should be `Apple`.
The output of `Process` should be `Process`.

I need a regex that would capture the whole term if the expression is matched but would perform the replacement for a partial match.

I have used `s$` to get rid of the last character.

Comment: add some code, please

Comment: See [*Good way to add terms to python pattern singularize*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586591/good-way-to-add-terms-to-python-pattern-singularize)

Comment: Regex is not a good solution for this problem, your best bet for a python based solution is `ntlk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been talked about WAY too many times, and the consensus is always: its WAY too complicated to be handled through a simple regex. All of the solutions fail with these examples:

```
apples
carrots
process
processes
tennis
```

A solution is to use [morpha](https://github.com/knowitall/morpha):

```
git clone https://github.com/knowitall/morpha
cd morpha/
flex -i -Cfea -8 -omorpha.yy.c morpha.lex
gcc -o morpha morpha.yy.c
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jhlau/predom_sense/master/lemmatiser_tools/morpha/verbstem.list > verbstem.list
```

now to test:

```
cat test.txt | ./morpha -c
apple
carrot
process
process
tennis
```

If you want a python solution, i suggest you go with `nltk`.

```
virtualenv env-nltk
source env-nltk/bin/activate
pip install nltk
python -c "import nltk; nltk.download()" # <- just get the whole thing, click "all" and then "download" on the "collections" tab
```

Now that everything is downloaded, lets fire off `python` and play with it.

```
>>> from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> lmtzr.lemmatize('apples')
u'apple'
>>> lmtzr.lemmatize('tennis')
'tennis'
>>> lmtzr.lemmatize('process')
'process'
>>> lmtzr.lemmatize('processes')
u'process'
```

Comment: Hi Javier, thanks for the answer. I have been using snowball stemmer, however snowball stemmer stems even the 'e' if preceded by a 's'. I didnt actually think of WordNetLemmatizer. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: One other thing is that WordNetLemmatizer wouldn't take care of "apple's". Do you know of any other stemmer that could handle this scenario and the earlier ones (apples, process)

Comment: @Sam maybe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect ?? i don't know, my naive first attempt would be to say: `re.sub("'(s?)($| )", '\g<1>\g<2>', "apples' apple's")` run it through here first then, `.lemmatize()` it -- if that doesn't help/work let me know and i could do a bit more research

Comment: Thanks Javier, Anyways, I have prepossessed my sentences to replace (') with a blank, so the "apple's" becomes "apples" and then I use lemmatize. lemme check if all works perfect. I will let you know if I face any problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use this negative lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<!s)s$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE5uV0/2)

**Breakup:**

```
(?<!s)  # assert previous position doesn't have 's'
s       # match 's'
$       # assert end of line
```

Comment: `Processes` will result in `Processe`

Comment: Right there can be other words in English like that also. It is as per the OP's requirement *I would like to retain the (s) if it is preceded by another (s)*

Comment: I would hardly call it a requirement, i would say more like a very superficial example. This "solution" only seems to work with those two examples, but fails with "tennis" and like @WiktorStribiżew said; "Processes"

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative lookbehind assertion to ensure substitution happens only if `s` is not preceded by another `s`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!s)s$', '', 'Apples')
'Apple'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!s)s$', '', 'Process')
'Process'
```